# AWS Lambda function with terraform

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform-provider-aws

Having some issue when applying my terraform plan, and cannot pinpoint what is the problem in it. I tried everything I could think about. Here is my lambda.tf file:

```
data "archive_file" "projectLeo_listunsubscribe_lambda_code" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/../src/ProjectLeo.ListUnsubscribe"
  output_path = "${path.module}/../src/code-packaged/list-unsubscribe.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "projectLeot_list_unsubscribe_lambda" {
  filename                       = "${data.archive_file.projectLeo_listunsubscribe_lambda_code.output_path}"
  function_name                  = "projectLeo-listunsubscribe-lambda"
  role                           = "${aws_iam_role.projectLeo_list_hygiene_role.arn}"
  handler                        = "${var.lambda_list_unsubscribe_function_handler}"
  runtime                        = "dotnetcore2.1"
  memory_size                    = "256"
  timeout                        = 120
  publish                        = true
  reserved_concurrent_executions = 1

  environment {
    variables = {
      optout-topic-arn = "${data.aws_sns_topic.projectLeo_optout_topic.arn}"
    }
  }
}

data "aws_sns_topic" "projectLeo_optout_topic" {
  name = "${var.sns_optout_topic_name}"
}
```

The plan generated looks all fine, ut this error is generated when apply is done:

```
Error: Error creating Lambda function: ValidationException:
        status code: 400, request id: c16dc369-bccd-418d-a2b5-2d0383c66064

  on ..\list-unsubscribe\infrastructure\lambda.tf line 9, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "projectLeo_list_unsubscribe_lambda":
   9: resource "aws_lambda_function" "projectLeo_list_unsubscribe_lambda" {
```

That's quite a light log to work with, I tried updating pieces by pieces of the code but always have the same result.

Can anybody help me pinpoint what may be the issue with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Did you create aws_iam_role?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. Yeah IAM role was defined, the issue was on the environment variable itself, as explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally manage to identify the issue: the environment variables in AWS lambda function doesn't accept hyphen (-). I replaced it by underscore and it went through.

optout-topic-arn became optout_topic_arn